# Unity 2d game: How to change aim line (line Renderer) dots?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I am working on a small game project for a  shooter with aim line and I was able to make this aim line  with Line Renderer but I can't change the shape of that line. I wanted something like little round dots. It seems to me that it would have something to do with the Default-particle in the Inspector Tab but how do I change that stuff? Do I create the material and replace it? if so how?

I put here some images of how the aim line are in this moment, how  the Inspector Tab are and my code of the Line Renderer. Thanks so much for some help.

Pics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/35GrA.jpg

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
[Range(1, 5)]
[SerializeField] private int _maxIterations = 5;

[SerializeField] private float _maxDistance = 25f;

public int _count;
public LineRenderer _line;
public int ammo;

public Transform Firepoint;
public GameObject BulletPrefab;
public GameObject FirePrefab;


private void Start()
{
    _line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && ammo > 0)
    {
        Shoot();
    }

    _count = 0;
    _line.SetVertexCount(1);
    _line.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
    _line.enabled = true;
    RayCast(transform.position, transform.right);
}

private void Shoot()
{
    //shooting logic
    var destroyBullet = Instantiate(BulletPrefab, Firepoint.position, Firepoint.rotation);
    ammo--;
    Destroy(destroyBullet, 10f);
    var destroyFire = Instantiate(FirePrefab, Firepoint.position, Firepoint.rotation);
    Destroy(destroyFire, 0.3f);
}

private bool RayCast(Vector2 position, Vector2 direction)
{
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(position, direction, _maxDistance);
    if (hit && _count <= _maxIterations - 1)
    {
        _count++;
        var reflectAngle = Vector2.Reflect(direction, hit.normal);
        _line.SetVertexCount(_count + 1);
        _line.SetPosition(_count, hit.point);
        RayCast(hit.point + reflectAngle, reflectAngle);
        return true;
    }

    if (hit == false)
    {
        _line.SetVertexCount(_count + 2);
        _line.SetPosition(_count + 1, position + direction * _maxDistance);
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `LineRenderer` component change `Texture Mode` to `Tile`, and make sure `Corner Vertices` are set to at least `1`.

If your line width is something other than 1, make sure to modify the `Tiling` `X` property of the material with the inverse of your line renderer width.

Example: Line width: `0.25`, Material x tiling: `1.0 / 0.25 = 4`.

[image]

Comment: Iggy, i changed the values like you said but didn`t notice any changes in the aim line. https://imgur.com/5PGpiwJ

Comment: @tigrev check your material and texture. Make sure the texture is a single ball and that `wrap mode` is set to `repeat`.

Comment: I,m sorry, @Iggy. Where i find that? I have Default-Particle in the material and i can,t find that single ball material...see above https://imgur.com/JfOi35C

Comment: @tigrev ah right, the default particle won't be visible in the project. You will have to import your own texture in order to modify the details. Also by the look of it, it seems you're on a different version of Unity? I'm on 2019.3.0a6 and so it may be different.